# How to pass Blackboard login data to cURL using --data?

Tags: bash, curl, blackboard

I am trying to curl a page on blackboard (a popular course management system for colleges). The page requires a login to my blackboard account, and I have read that you can do this using the --data argument. What I don't know, is what format I need to use to pass my username and password to the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use firefox as your browser you can let create the browser the curl command.

You need to active the developer tools (on win F12) and after your login you can go to the POST line press the right mouse button and select **save as curl** or similar wording.

As described here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Copy_as_cURL

Well okay the answer is.

curl -v --data 'username=abc124&password=password'

Maybe you can take a look into the brand new book

"Everything curl"
https://www.gitbook.com/book/bagder/everything-curl/details

at the HTTP Post chapter or you can take a look into the **http-scripting** at the homepage of curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I should have been more specific in my post. I actually need to use the "curl" command, it is part of a script I am writing.

Comment: Ähm yes. You make the step above **once** copy the curl command and use it in the script. You will adopt the curl command with some variables to be flexible about the username and the password. Maybe I have misunderstood you?

Comment: To be clear, I'm running the curl command inside a loop in my script. I'm aware that I can login and see the data in a browser, but I need to access it strictly through the command line. Say for instance my username is "abc123" and my password is "password". How would I use these parameters in the --data argument?

Comment: curl -v --data 'username=abc124&password=password' <YOUR-URL> maybe you can take a look into the brand new book "Everything curl" https://www.gitbook.com/book/bagder/everything-curl/details at the chapter http://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html or into the http-scripting do at the homepage of curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST

Answer (score 0):

I am from Sun Yat-sen University, I login our school blackboard with the below scripts. It used `RCurl` package. Detail information your can find in my [github](http://github.com/kongdd/RCurl_project).

```
library(V8)
library(xml2)
source('../R/MainFunction.R', encoding = 'UTF-8')

url <-list(
  login_netid = "https://cas.sysu.edu.cn/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Felearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn%2Fwebapps%2Fbb-caszsdx-bb_bb60%2Findex.jsp",
  login_origin = "http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn/webapps/login/",
  referer = "http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn/",
  userinfo = "http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn/webapps/portal/execute/topframe?tab_tab_group_id=_22_1&frameSize=LARGE",
  main = "http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn/webapps/portal/frameset.jsp"
)

## your can also directly login using cookies from firefox or other browser
myHttpheader<- c(
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
  "Accept" = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate",
  "Accept-Language" = "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
  "Connection"="keep-alive",
  # "Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=DD1F84CD54D9831F8065A5026039A9CC.root; safedog-flow-item=AE46F7B8895D4633E2C87C0C0809A2EB; session_id=D15553506517F2E4E65E8CCD6F8F3DCA; JSESSIONID=36FBE15A073E5FACDD6DB6A61E6ADB45.root; xythosdrive=0",
  DNT = 1,
  "Host" = "elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn",
  # Referer = url$referer, 
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" = 1)
h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
ch <- getCurlHandle()#带上百宝箱开始上路
tmp <- curlSetOpt(curl = ch, 
           cainfo="pem/cacert.pem",
           ssl.verifyhost=FALSE,
           ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,
           followlocation = TRUE,
           verbose = TRUE, 
           cookiejar = "cookies_elearn.txt", cookiefile = "cookies_elearn.txt",
           httpheader = myHttpheader)
# login -------------------------------

tmp <- getURL(url$login_origin, curl = ch, headerfunction = h$update)
one_time_token <- read_html(tmp) %>% xml_find_all("//input[@name='one_time_token']") %>% xml_attr("value")

ct <- v8()
ct$source("blackboard.js")
pwd <- "****"
user <- "****"
encode_pws <- ct$call("kong", one_time_token, pwd)

params <- list(
  action="login",
  auth_type="",
  encoded_pw=encode_pws[1],
  encoded_pw_unicode=encode_pws[2],
  login = "登陆",#iconv("登陆", "gb2312", "utf-8") %>% URLencode(),
  new_loc =" ",#"%C2%A0", #" ",
  one_time_token=one_time_token,
  password = "",
  "remote-user"="",
  user_id = user)
page <- postForm(url$login_origin, .params = params, curl = ch,
                 # origin="http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn", refere="http://elearning.ne.sysu.edu.cn/",
                 style="post") %T>% print

# p <- params2URL(url$login_origin, params) %>% getURL(curl = ch)
# get data ----------------------------------------------------------------
p <- getURL(url$userinfo, curl = ch) 
grep("孔冬冬", p)#now you can find your name in p
```